# Formal logic sentence for nested if/else

Tags: math, logic

If I want to write sentence "if A then B else C" in formal logic, I can:

```
(A -> B)  V  (~A -> C)
```

How can I write the same in this form (I don't remember how was called this form like "rational"):

```
A -> B ???
----------
  C ???
```

Real question is: I have many nested "if .. else" and second form seems more natural to write such nested if's. I can write nested "if.. else" if first form, but I don't know how to write them in second, because I don't know how to write single "if.. ELSE" in the second form (due to "else" clause). Is it possible even?

Comment: You mention "writing" repeatedly. What language are you using to write these logical expressions? If it is not a computer language the question is off-topic for this site. If it is a computer language you need to say which one, since capabilities and philosophies differ among languages.

Comment: Your first formula is just a tautology now: you should replace the disjunction connective with the conjunction. I do not think that natural-deduction-style or sequential-calculi-style formalisms are suitable for your purposes. Use binary decision trees for graphical representation of nested if-then-else.

Comment: Stas, hello. Why is it tautology? Tautology is `A & A` and ` A | A`, but I have `(A ...) | (~A ...)`. It's like `A -> B; C` in Prolog. Or am I miss something?

Comment: @Paul-AG, just construct a truth table for this first formula.

Comment: @Paul-AG You know that A -> B is equivalent to (B v not A), so (A->B) v (not A -> C) is equivalent to ((B v not A) v (C v not not A)), which simplifies to (A v not A v B v C). So you see that the part (A v not A) is always satisfied, i.e. tautology.

Comment: @Bromind, looks right. Makes sense.